# Cannot Create Directory "No such file or directory"

Tags: mount, live-usb, disk, live-environment

I'm attempting to copy some old files out of a bricked windows drive - using the "Try Ubuntu before installing" method- before I reinstall a clean copy of Windows onto it.

When I load up the trial version, I'm running

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw /media/ubuntu/XYZ_DRIVE
```

for both drives, but when trying to copy the files, I get the same error;

> Error opening X/Y/Z: no such file or directory

I can see the drives in Files and can look through the dives, but as soon as I try to transfer files, it stops functioning altogether. I've tried using files and using `cp`, but neither work. I've done this in the past with absolutely no problems. What's my issue?

(Note this same error occurs when attempting to make a directory using `mkdir`, as well as manually in files. It would seem that the disks can be viewed but not accessed)

***Update:*** By unmounting and remounting the drives from files, I was able to get some files *from* the bricked disk onto the live session, but I am still not able to get them onto the storage drive. **As soon as I attempt to make the storage drive read-write, the errors start.**

Comment: Where are you trying to write the files?  Sure a different device?  (if it's the same device did you verify the drive's health? as to me it would be a wasteful idea).  I'd also suggest checking your `mount` command as it looks wrong to me.

Comment: @guiverc I'm moving to a different drive, and drive health is not the problem, as I was able to get the files onto my live session. As for the mount command, what looks wrong?

Comment: `remount, rw` looks wrong, remove the space after the comma.

Comment: the hanging "," separating operands with only a single operand..  it screams that you mis-typed something..